# Laplace Problem : How to solve this integral?

Tags: integration

As far as I know the Laplace transform of $(1/t)$ is infinite. But the problem I have been given is

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t} - e^{-4t}}{t}\,dt.$$

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Look at $\int_0^{\infty} (e^{-t}-e^{-at})dt/t$.

Comment: It is often useful to look at $\lim\limits_{a\to0}\int_a^\infty\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-4t}}t\,\mathrm{d}t$. This can be separated into two convergent integrals, the limit of whose differences is easier to compute.

Comment: This can be viewed as a Frullani integral. There are plenty of online sources and in-site posts.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Lee David Chung Lin, this integral is a classic [Frullani integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral) for which we have the result
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}x \mathrm{d}x=(f(0)-\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t))\ln{\left(\frac{b}a\right)}$$
So your integral has $f(x)=e^{-x}$ for which the corresponding result is
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-4x}}x \mathrm{d}x=(e^{-0}-\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-t})\ln{\left(\frac{4}1\right)}=2\ln{(2)}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Can this problem be solved using Laplace Transform?
the book from which i got this explicitly stated to use Laplace Transform to evaluate it.....